# How do I unit test a non-generic method that calls a generic method in a sealed non-generic class?

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks

using `[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo()]` and

```
public sealed class AppService
{
    //TODO: fix dev's spelling
    //want to test this
    public AddSubscribtionResponse AddSubscribtion(AddSubscribtionRequest request)
    {
        return ExecuteQueryProc<AddSubscribtionResponse>("spAddAppToUserGroup", request).First();
    }

    //I want to stub or interaction test the call to here
    #if DEBUG
    internal
    #endif
    List<T> ExecuteQueryProc<T>(string query, object parameters = null)
    {
        var cn=GetConnection();
        //DatabaseCommand is a static class =(
        return DatabaseCommand.ExecuteQueryProc<T>(cn, query, parameters);
    }
}
```

Every attempt I've made at getting Rhino to stub or intercept the Execute Query proc method has failed.

```
var service = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<AppService>(null);
service.Stub(f => f.ExecuteQueryProc<AddSubscribtionRequest>(null, null)).IgnoreArguments().Return(new List<AddSubscribtionRequest>());

var expected = new AddSubscribtionRequest();
var actual = service.AddSubscribtion(expected);
```

Throws 
`System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "sealed" from your class (Rhino.Mocks can't proxy your class if it can't inherit from it). And ExecuteQueryProc has to be virtual to be able to stub its functionality.

Comment: it is set to virtual, and when I had it non-sealed I was not able to mock it.

Comment: Could you clarify what "not able to mock it" means?  Did you get any errors?  Please update the question to show the new code you're testing (after making the method virtual and the class non-sealed).

Comment: not able to mock it meaning the call went to the original, and was not intercepted.

Comment: Please update the question with the class definition and method signatures (code not required).  Also include the complete "InternalsVisibleTo" attribute definition so we can see if that is correct.

Comment: which class definition? that is the exact class definition under test. The internals visible to is working, because visual studio intellisense sees all the internal methods.

Comment: The one you're trying to mock.

Comment: that is the class I'm trying to mock in the initial question